# Why does sublime text not allow my code to run properly?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a login system for users.

This is my code:

```
def register():
    db = open("database.txt", "r")
    Username = input("Create Username:")
    Password = input("Create Password:")
    Password1 = input("Conform Password")

    if Password != Password1:
        print("Passwords do not match, restart")
        register()
    else:
        #checks length of Password
        if len(Password)<=6:
            print("Password is too short restart:")
            register()
        elif Username in db: # checks if the Username is in the database
            print("Username exists")
            register()
        else:
            db = open("database.txt", "a")
            db.write(Username+", "+Password+"\n") # "/n" creates a new line
            print("Success")

register()
```

This code is meant to output a request for the user to create a username then a password and then a confirmation of that password.
This only outputs a request for a user to create a username but not a password in sublime text.
I have tested this code in IDLE and it works perfectly.

Comment: I don't think Sublime can do interactive user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why there is a problem with sublime, but what I know is that you have made several mistakes writing that code. Here is correct version:

```
import os


def register():
    if not os.path.exists("database.txt"): # if file does not exist, then create it
        with open("database.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write("\n")
    with open("database.txt", "r") as f:
        db = f.read()
    Username = input("Create Username: ")
    Password = input("Create Password: ")
    Password1 = input("Conform Password: ")
    
    if Password != Password1:
        print("Passwords do not match, restart")
        register()
    else:
        #checks length of Password
        if len(Password)<=6:
            print("Password is too short, restart")
            register()
        elif Username in [line.split(", ")[0] for line in db.split("\n")]: # checks if the Username is in the database (line.split(", ")[0] extracts username)
            print("Username exists")
            register()
        elif ", " in Username:
            print("Username must not contain \", \"")
            register()
        else:
            with open("database.txt", "w") as f:
                f.write(Username + ", " + Password + "\n" + db) # "\n" creates a new line
            print("Success")

register()
```

And do you know that you can't call a function inside if it's own for infinite many times? The recursion limit is something around 1000. So you will get exception after many restarts.

Comment: Thank you for the improved code but I am still having the same issue. Executes the code, I enter a username but it does not ask for a password.

Comment: @Alex Bartram , it seems like `input` function does not work properly. Try starting yout program from command line with `python filename.py`.